# Control the visibility of GridView Footer based on a property within the Data

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

I am working on a project where I have to show the `Footer` of the `Gridview` if a certain property is available in the Data which has been loaded in the `Gridview`.
I use a custom `DataTemplateSelector` class to present data in the `Gridview` but the property exists in the main class.

```
public class ItemTemplateData
{
  public string PropertyToShowFooter {get; set;}
}
// other classes derive from this main class
public class VideoItemTemplateData : ItemTemplateData
{
  // other properties not related here
}
```

Now, it works as expected if I explicitly create a `Footer` as `DataTemplate` in `Gridview` but if I create a `DataTemplate` in a `Dictionary` and try to use it, it doesn't work. It always shows the `Footer` whether the property is empty or not. I use a `Converter` to convert the property to control the `Visibility`.

UPDATE:

No code/method is working !!! It always shows the Footer or hides it, no matter what.

```
// First method that I tried
<Gridview>
....
<GridView.FooterTemplate>
    <DataTemplate
        x:DataType="data:ItemTemplateData">
        <UserControl>
            <HyperlinkButton
                Visibility="{x:Bind PropertyToShowFooter, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibleConverter}}"
                Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"
                Style="{StaticResource GridViewFooterLinkStyle}"/>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
</GridView.FooterTemplate>
</Gridview>

// 2nd method that I tried and really want this one to work.
<DataTemplate
        x:Key="GridViewCustomFooterTemplate"
        x:DataType="data:ItemTemplateData">
    <UserControl>
    <HyperlinkButton
        Visibility="{x:Bind PropertyToShowFooter, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibleConverter}}"
        Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"
        Style="{StaticResource GridViewFooterLinkStyle}"/>
    </UserControl>
</DataTemplate>

<GridView
     FooterTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewCustomFooterTemplate}"/>
```

More details for `TemplateSelector`:

```
public class DataTemplateSelectorClass : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate VideoItemTemplate { get; set; }


    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is VideoItemTemplateData)
        {
            return VideoItemTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
    }
}
```

The `Footer` is just a simple `HyperlinkButton` and it should be visible or collapsed based on the converter. If there is a non-empty string in the property it will be visible otherwise it will be collapsed.

Converter for Visiblity from String:

```
public class StringToVisiblity : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is string && value != null)
        {
            if (value.ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I am not sure as how the Footer will determine its `DataContext` from the `Gridview`'s items. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: How did you write the selector in code behind? What's your logic to show or hide the footer? Can you provide us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Generally speaking, you need to verify your PropertyToShowFooter property in your selector so that your UI can render the right template based on your property. However your request is not clear based on your post.

Comment: I updated the question altogether with new code/details. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer has to know where to get the value. If the list contains multiple items, it cannot know which one it should use. To make binding in footer template work, you have to directly set the `Footer` property to the instance it should work with:

```
<GridView Footer="{x:Bind TheOneItemTemplateData}"> ... </GridView>
```

Comment: It works. I had to bind the first item of the ItemsControl to the footer property and it works. `Visibility="{Binding Items[0].Property, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"` Thanks

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding!